# Cleanup old /dev/pts files?

Tags: permissions, aix

My company has a policy that sweeps all files on our AIX servers to see if any are world writeable. They are upset because there are some files in /dev/pts (a few with me as owner) that are world writeable, though this is a complete non-issue as far as I know. I presume some are orphaned as they're from last year, and I was wondering if there's any way to clean them up other than a server reboot?

Thanks